# Symfony2 provider in_memory, logout and special user

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a protected area with Symfony2.

I don't have a User Class so i have my users in `security.yml` like :

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                test:  { password: test, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
```

And my firewall is :

```
firewalls:
    dashboard:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        logout: true
        http_basic:
            realm: "Secured Demo Area"
            provider: in_memory
```

So, with this, when i go to /admin i have the login form and it's ok if i login with test/test for example.

Is there a way to configure the seesion time with this ?

Is there a way to force logout ?

Is there a way to specify, for this firewall, just check in users in_memory with role admin ?

Comment: I would avoid "http_basic" like the plague, quite honestly. Setting up a login form is fairly easy and , dare I say it, fun. :D Also, FOSUserBundle makes it stupid easy. :P